# Slowing down the delay between "frames" in a CSS animation?

Tags: css, animation

I have a CSS animation thats rather intensive on the users machine (notably my macbook spins up the fans like crazy when its running the animation over the course of 5 minutes infinitely). I suspect its because the browser is updating the hue-rotate filter (on a full page background) every redraw the browser can which is slowing things down significantly.

Here is the animation in question:

```
@keyframes rotatehue {
  0% {

    filter: hue-rotate(100deg);
  }
  63% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {

    filter: hue-rotate(100deg);
  }
}
```

And here is the animation property used:

```
animation: rotatehue 300s linear infinite;
```

Is there any way, as its a long animation where the minute changes between each frame is not required, to say "only update this animation every 0.5 seconds" or so?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question. Can you explain better please?

Comment: As far as I am aware CSS animations are updated every redraw the browser does (much like when you use requestAnimationFrame in javascript). I am wondering as the filter is a computationaly expensive thing to animate to essentially lower the animations frame rate so it does not slow down the browser when the animation is playing

Comment: I don't think you can do that, maybe I am wrong... however, try activating hardware acceleration for the element by setting `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)`

Comment: Ah, thats unfortunate, thanks for your answer @Skatch unfortunately that did not solve the issue at hand but I guess its impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decrease the CPU rendering time by using a steps() as the animation-timing-function.

This property is applied on a keyframe basis; since your keyframes are not simetrical, it would be better to set different number of steps on each rule

```css
.base {
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/750);
    background-size: cover;
    animation: rotatehue infinite 12s;
}


@keyframes rotatehue {
    0% { animation-timing-function: steps(3);  
         -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg); }
   63% { animation-timing-function: steps(2);  
         -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(360deg); }
  100% { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
```

I have set the steps number too low on purpose to demonstrate the idea- adjust it per your needs